# implementing binary trees - data structure, trie

Tags: binary-tree, trie

Binary trees. The principal is understandable, but what do they really looks like in terms of arrays or associative arrays?

if the data structures I have available to me are:

```
AssociativeArray={tag:value,tag:value,tag:value} 

(of course, each tag is unique)
```

and

```
Array=[value,value,value] 
(where the value can be any data type including array)
```

examples:

```
DictOfWords={greeting:"hello",sound:"music",sleep:"dream",words:["hello","music","dream"]}
listOfWords=["hello","music","dream",DictOfWords]
```

what would a binary tree built out of one or both of those look like?

further, what would the data structure for a trie for word search look like built from those data structures?

What would a node of a trie look like? Would it be an Associative Array or a linear array or some combination of the two? I understand [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017436/implementing-a-trie-data-structure) that "A trie holds one node per character"

so would the top level structure be something like:

trie={a:{},b:{},c:{}...}

or

trie={a:[],b:[],c:{}...}

or

trie=["a","b","c"...]

Comment: Could you go to wikipedia and look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie .  If those don't answer your questions, come back and post a comment here, and I'll help you understand them.

Comment: That's exactly what I did before coming back to S/O and posting this question!

Comment: I guess what is confusing me, then, is why you want to phrase them in terms of associative arrays or arrays.  Associative Arrays and Arrays are not the usual way to think of Binary Trees.  In fact, I've only heard of it used that way in one context (it was a fancy optimization).  Meanwhile, the Trie page gives several examples in various languages that are effectively built from associative arrays.  Dukeling's answer shows the issue: you can invent any representation you please, but the useful representations for understanding do not involve arrays or associative arrays.

Comment: Trying to phrase this different ways: there are plenty of ways to notate the content of a binary tree as an array or an associative array.  However, none of the operations done on binary trees really use an array function, and there are several operations done on balanced binary trees that are unimplementable if you choose to think of them as arrays.

Comment: All I have to work with is these two types of arrays. I don't know what other built-in data type could be used - string, int, longint, float, double, array, associative array, that's all. Can't see how anyone could iterate through a list of anything without using an array and some kind of array index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tries and Binary Trees are usually not thought of as arrays or associative arrays.  They are thought of as collections of nodes, usually implemented as a struct.  For example, binary trees tend to look like

```
struct BTreeNode
{
    value_type value;
    BTreeNode* left;
    BTreeNode* right;
};
```

And Tries tend to look like

```
struct TrieNode
{
    char_type  letter;
    associative_array<char_type, TrieNode*> children;
};
```

Now if you are only looking to model this with arrays and associative arrays, the question is going to be: what do you intend to do with them?  If all you need to do is store data in a tree/trie structure, you have a lot of options.  However, if you actually want to use a BTree as a BTree or a Trie as a Trie, we have to make sure that whatever transformation you use to convert structures to arrays/associative arrays works.  The easiest one: treat each struct as an associative array with a constant number of entries

```
    4
   / \
  2   5
 / \   \
1   3   6
```

Would be usually done as

```
BTreeNode oneNode(1, null, null);
BTreeNode threeNode(3, null, null);
BTreeNode twoNode(2, oneNode, threeNode);
BTreeNode sixNode(6, null, null);
BTreeNode fiveNode(5, null, sixNode);
BTreeNode fourNode(4, twoNode, fiveNode);
```

You can do a 1-to-1 conversion of those structs to associative arrays and get

```
fourNode = {   value: 4,
               left: {
                   value: 2,
                   left: {
                       value: 1
                   },
                   right: {
                       value: 3
                   }
               },
               right: {
                   value: 5,
                   right: {
                       value:6
                   }
              }
          }
```

*There is a comparable conversion to arrays, but it is less obvious to read*

A comparable trie storing "abc" "abd" "abe" "ace" creates a trie structure that looks like

```
    a
   / \
  b    c
/ | \   \
```

c  d  e   e

Doing the same conversion from structs to values as above, you get

```
trie =  {
            letter: 'a',
            children: {
                'b': {
                    letter: 'b'
                    children: {
                        'c': { letter: 'c' },
                        'd': { letter: 'd' },
                        'e': { letter: 'e' }
                    }
                'c': {
                    letter: 'c'
                    children: {
                        'e': { letter: 'e' }
                    }
            }
       }
```

However, standing by my original comments, "what do they really looks like in terms of arrays or associative arrays?" is unanswerable.  They don't actually get implemented as arrays or associative arrays at all, so "really look like" cannot be used alongside "arrays or associative arrays."  Think of them in terms of the node structures that they are really constructed from, and you will go much further.

For example, there is an idea of a self balancing binary tree.  Those structures are very easy to understand if you think of the structures as a bunch of nodes linked together.  If you try to think of a self balancing binary tree in terms of arrays/associative arrays, you will have a LOT of trouble, because they tend to have a pointer back to their parent, which creates really messed up looking associative arrays.

```
struct SelfBalancingBTreeNode
{
    value_type value;
    SelfBalancingBTreeNode* parent;
    SelfBalancingBTreeNode* left;
    SelfBalancingBTreeNode* right;
};
```

To model this you need to have really interesting associative array structures

```
leftNode = { value: 1, parent: null, left: null, right: null}
parentNode = value: 2, parent: null, left: leftNode, right: null}
leftNode['parent'] = parentNode
```

Which creates cycles that are not commonly thought of when using associative arrays

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful, the language i'm working with doesn't support a pure struct like that, so I *have* to use either arrays, associative arrays, or both. Your SelfBalancingBTreeNode structure does look remarkably like an AA though, and I can see how it might look as an Array as well (which would be faster to access). I think I know enough now to start doing some programming to test out the concepts here.

Answer (score 2):

**Binary tree:**

```
     1
   /   \
  2     3
 / \   / \
4   5 6   7
```

Can be represented as:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Thus a node at index `i`'s children are at indices `2i` and `2i+1`.

Or it can be represented as:

```
{1:[2,3], 2:[4,5], 3:[6,7]}
```

With a reference to the root somewhere.

**Trie:**

```
      1
  a /   \ b
   2     3
a / \ b
 4   5
```

Can be represented as:

```
{1:{a:2, b:3},
 2:{a:4, b:5},
 3:{},
 4:{},
 5:{}
}
```

Comment: Every website discussing b-trees uses that ascii line diagram you used that has no obvious correlation to a data structure, that is exactly why I'm asking this question. I think I see where you are going with it, but I have some questions: array [1,2,3,4,5] is an array of int, not an array of AAs. so you maybe mean {1:{a:2,b:3},2:{a:4,b:5}} or [{a:2,b:3},{a:4,b:5}]  except {a:2,b:3} would be the zeroth element of the array, so perhaps [{a:1,b:2},{c:3,d:4}] where the array index itself would be the count [0,1,2,3,4] ?

Comment: @alphablender I more intended for the numbers to be interpreted as objects. Edited with something clearer.