# Tab Completion and Partial Completion

Tags: c, parsing, console

I would like to make a program which accepts commands in a way similar to that of `ip` on Linux. For example, I want to have a full command of `show interface options` but the user could type in just `show in options` or even just `s i o` if they did not conflict with other commands.

I have some ideas of how to go about this, and I would like to do this in C. So the question is what would be a good way of going about this while remaining as portable as possible between Linux/UNIX systems.

My first thought is to have a linked list. Each list item to point to the next command in an array of strings, with the final command having the address to a function call (please excuse my sloppy pseudocode).

**header.h**

```
typedef int8_t (__cdecl *proc_stub)(void *data, uint16_t len);
typedef struct s_proc_stub
{
    char command[16];
    proc_stub proc;
    struct s_proc_stub *next;
};
struct s_proc_stub proc_list[] =
{
    { "cmd", CommandFunction, ... },
    { "set", SetFunction, ... },
    ...
};
```

I feel like one downfall of this may be extra CPU and RAM utilisation. It may also be prone to error which can lead to vulnerabilities. This process will be facing the Internet, so I would like to ensure the security of the code.

My next thought was to use strtok() and just do an strnicmp() against each token. Another alternative is to use pointer arithmetic to simulate strtok() faster and without modifying the buffer. I feel like strtok is the most straight forward approach and the least error prone, but I want to say that I recall strtok() has some extra overhead compared to the other two methods.

The target platform for this is a Raspberry Pi, which has only about 2GB of RAM to work with. The drives are frequently quite small, and the CPU is okay but not ideal for heavy processing. I anticipate the processes being under heavy load from command processing, so I would like the ideal solution for minimising the amount of RAM and CPU usage. I would love to hear some methods that I am not aware of! :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie?

Comment: `strnicmp` is not always available. The Posix function is `strcasecmp`, which is available in glibc. These functions may or may not be locale-aware, but a locale-aware version is going to have a lot more overhead than `strtok`, fwiw.

Comment: @rici yes thank you, i found an implementation on here in C and modified it for my use. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733786/c99-remove-stricmp-and-strnicmp

Comment: The implementation in the question you link will not work with UTF-8 encoded strings, and it will only work with ISO-8859-x single-byte codes if your locale is correctly set up (and it is an ISO-8859-x locale, which is pretty rare these days, I think.) It's fine but excessive if you are only comparing plain ascii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a trie (prefix tree) data-structure is appropriate, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie; specifically, minimising the amount of memory, one may prefer a compact prefix tree, (radix tree.) From, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree:

> In a trie, all comparisons require constant time, but it takes m comparisons to look up a string of length m. Radix trees can perform these operations with fewer comparisons, and require many fewer nodes.

Here is an implementation, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31718868/2472827.

Comment: Yes that is perfect! Basically what I was thinking, but this seems to be better defined in method and implementation. Thanks for the information! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this might be useful or not, but if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, take a look at [GNU readline](https://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), the library used for this kind of stuff in GNU/Linux.

Comment: I would prefer to maintain the code within my own program without external libraries, but I will keep the method in mind.  :)